# How to connect two web applications under one login?

Tags: php, session, yii

I have created two very different web applications using Yii. They both share the same database and they both use the same tables to log in. Both web applications have a link towards each other. What I'm trying to achieve is if a user happens to login to any of the apps (let's say app 1), they can transfer from app 1 to app 2 without having to login and vice versa.

I looked for session initiation and I researched that it should be found in UserIdentity.php but when I checked, there were no sessions being initiated at all. I'm not going to post code for now since the codes are working fine, it's just that I need to know how to make the user experience more flowing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with YII but I think that it probably uses a unique string within the session for each site, and probably also sets/matches for a unique cookie that it uses to determine which site the user is logged into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the applications are on the same server, you can follow [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/135/single-sign-on-across-multiple-subdomains/). Basiclly you have to set the same (cookie) for both applications, and set a session path. You can also save the sessions to a database table ([See Larry Ullman's article on this)](http://www.larryullman.com/2011/05/03/using-sessions-with-the-yii-framework/) as an alternative.

Comment: The first article was exactly what I needed, and it steered me towards the right direction, but now I'm facing a whole set of problems. I've asked a new question that covers it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to consider is that you have to make your session cookies available for both domains:

**1)** If your applications are on subdomains you can make it avaliable like this **before starting to** `session_start()`:

```
    session_set_cookie_params(0,'/','.yourdomain.com');
```

And your session data is available under all subdomains. Easy huh

---

**2)** If your applications are on different domains there is a good article for that

[Building and implementing a Single Sign-On solution](http://merbist.com/2012/04/04/building-and-implementing-a-single-sign-on-solution/)
[secure-and-flexible-cross-domain-sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806701/secure-and-flexible-cross-domain-sessions)

*Also make sure that you read about session and cookie security and implement them*

Comment: According to #1. Would this mean that I have to add a condition to EVERY page that I have to make sure it's within a session? I'm using Yii framework by the way.

Comment: @user3278616 I haven't used Yii framework, but yes you need to check the session where you need it