# Sharing session between applications Redis

Tags: php, laravel, session, redis

I have this setup on AWS:

1. Aplication with php5.6
2. Aplication with Laravel 6
3. LoadBalancer
4. ElasticCache Redis

The LoadBalancer send few routes to PHP and other to Laravel
I have installed php5 extension to use Redis and its working well;
I have installed predis on Laravel and are working to;

PHP session are saving like this:

```
"PHPREDIS_SESSION:3mm1j1s38io0qqsjo9h1i5k0e7" "1440" "id_log_acesso|s:8:\"22684247\";last_session|s:26:\"3mm1j1s38io0qqsjo9h1i5k0e7\";"
```

And the laravel saving like this:

```
_sessao_aplicacao_cache:8IITIOGBIDNWfuF3FpY47c03FSJx2yGzyQzsh3ny" "7200" "s:223:\"a:3:{s:6:\"_token\";s:40:\"StJV71z6IVC7W1Zme2m0GcI4wuNRhEtnWfwkGT7s\";s:9:\"_previous\";a:1:{s:3:\"url\";s:65:\"http://172.31.23.41/check-status-6d1127a34c48cd9722d16b7e20aaee70\";}s:6:\"_flash\";a:2:{s:3:\"old\";a:0:{}s:3:\"new\";a:0:{}}}\";"
```

**I'm using the same domain.**

My question is: How can I share the **session** between this aplications?

Comment: are your apps using same domain? I provided an answer for this earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966526/php-session-doesnt-work-in-angular-6-project/52967495#52967495

Comment: Yes, im using the same domain