# API call using angular 7 doesn't read PHP session variables

Tags: php, angular

I need to create simple login with angular and use sessions. 
for that i've two php files and angular files.

This is PHP file 1

```
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');


$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

if(isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata)) {

    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $username=trim($request->username);
    $password=trim($request->password);

  if($username == 'admin' && $password == 'admin') {
    $_SESSION['user'] = 'admin';
    ?>
{
  "success": true,
  "secret": "This is the secret no one knows but the admin"
}
    <?php
  } else {
    ?>
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "Invalid credentials"
}
    <?php
  }
} else {
  //var_dump($_POST)
  ?>
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "Only POST access accepted"
}
  <?php


}

?>
```

This is PHP file 2

```
    <?php
    session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');

    $user = $_SESSION['user'];

             echo '{
                "message": "'.$user.'",
                 "success": true   
             }';


        ?>
```

In one of my component's ngOnInit(), i've called both of these APIs (i know first one should be triggered in a login submit button, but for testing purpose i've used both under one.). I have even used  settimeout function to delay the second call

```
 ngOnInit() {


    this.auth.getUserDetails('admin','admin')
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('success',data);
        if(data.success){

        }
        else{
          window.alert("invalid");
        }

    },
      error=> {
        console.log('failed',error);


      }
  ) 
  var _this=this;
  setTimeout(function(){


    _this.user.getSomeData().subscribe(data=>{

      console.log(data);

    })

    }, 3000);


  }
```

But still user session is unavailable.. I need help to understand the reason.
Please check the image.
For first post request is success and but second get request is failed. 
It says session variable i used (user) is not available.
But that variable has been set by previous request.

[This is the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkIoA.png)

Thank you

Comment: You should put _this.user.getSomeData() inside first subscription. In this, it ensures the call will happen after session is created from this.auth.getUserDetails('admin','admin').

Comment: I tried that one too, But still its acting as if there is no $_SESSION['user'] set. 

    this.auth.getUserDetails('admin','admin')
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('success',data);
        if(data.success){

          let _this=this;
          _this.user.getSomeData().subscribe(data1=>{
        
            console.log(data1);
        
          })
          
        }
        else{
          window.alert("invalid");
        }

    },
      error=> {
        console.log('failed',error);
      

      }
  )

Comment: Seem the angular doesn't get the PHP Session ID. It will be the cause of it. When you use PHP $_SESSION, it will send the client an cookie, but when it's not then the session key won't be saved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue working on React and PHP locally, both using localhost but on different ports. [This answer helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37102215/10249680).

PHP sessions are stored on cookies, and when making cross-domain (or in this case cross-port) requests those cookies are not shared.

In your first login call to PHP, you need to return the session ID using session_id() and store this somewhere on your app. Then, when making further calls to PHP, make sure to pass it the same session id. You can then use session_id() again to set the id to the one you passed, which will keep the last session active:

```
if ($request->session_id) {
session_id($request->session_id);
}
start_session();
$json['session_id'] = session_id();
$json['user'] = $_SESSION['user'];
echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score -2):

You are Working on Two Different Server localhost:80 for PHP and Localhost:4200 for angular so your request for a session is Localhost:4200 This request can not access PHP session. 
so please set headers in angular for the PHP side request.